Question about remark in Kunens "Set Theory: An Introduction to Independence Proofs" regarding total orders.
On page 15 in Kunens "Set Theory: An Introduction to Independence Proofs", after introducing total orders, Kunen makes the following remark:
"Note that our definition does not assume that $R \subset A \times A$, so if $\langle A,R \rangle$ is a total order so is $\langle B,R \rangle$ whenever $B \subset A$."
Question: Why is the fact that we do not assume that $R \subset A \times A$ related to the fact that $\langle B,R \rangle$ is a total order for $B \subset A$? I can't see why they are related. It seems to follow just from the fact that $\langle A,R \rangle$ is a total order, that $\langle B,R \rangle$ is a total order (edit: whenever $B \subset A$), unless I am mistaken.
As the sentence is formulated, I am led to believe that Kunen means they are related. If so (that is, I am mistaken), in what sense?
Remark: $R$ is a relation above.

Let's make this concrete.  Let $R$ be the usual order on $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \}=A$.  Let $B = \{1, 2, 3 \}$.  Kunen is saying that the fact that $(4, 5) \in R$, so that $R$ is not a subset of $B \times B$, doesn't prevent $R$ from being a relation (in fact, a total order) on $B$.

I don't see the relevance: If $R \subset A \times A$, then what precludes $R \subset B \times B$? Yes, it can happen, as you show above, but you are not forced to conclude from $R \subset A \times A$ that $R \subset B \times B$ is false.

@Ben123 Nothing precludes $R \subseteq B \times B$, but the point is that $R$ is a relation on $B$ even if it doesn’t happen.  Some authors would say that my example is not a relation on $B$ because it contains ordered pairs with components outside of $B$.  Either definition is workable.  Kunen is just pointing out an advantage of his choice.
